# How do I convert a string from an input into an integer? (Python 3.9)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, input, integer

As you know, a user input in Python by default is a string. I tried converting them using the int() function after, however, it still stays as a string.
Code example:

```
number = input("Input a number: ")
int(number)
print(type(number))
```

This would give an output of: `<class 'str'>`
, even though I tried converting them to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the value, because `int()` doesn't apply on place.

`number = int(number)`

[`Python int() function`](https://www.w3resource.com/python/built-in-function/int.php#:%7E:text=The%20int()%20function%20converts,if%20no%20arguments%20are%20given.&text=A%20number%20or%20string%20to%20be%20converted%20to%20integer%20object.)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to assign the converted variable to your `number`:

```
number = input("Input a number: ")
number = int(number)
print(type(number))
```

Or directly like this:

```
number = int(input("Input a number: "))
print(type(number))
```

Comment: Whoops, somebody postet the answer a minute faster than me. How should I proceed? Delete my answer or leave it? @ExperiencedUserdOfSO :)